# JavaFX show object at runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, interface

i have a javafx application, i need to show/edit/manipulate some objects at runtime.
For example i have an anchorPane, when i click a button i need to set the pane visible, and during the execution of the logic, set some labels to visible.

here's my code:

```
//MyController.java
public class MyController extends AnchorPane {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane myPane;
    @FXML
    private Label label1;
    @FXML
    private Label label2;
    @FXML
    private Button button1;

    private Main application;
    public void setApp(Main application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                myPane.setVisile(true);.
                //long run action
                label1.setVisible(true);
                //long run action
                label2.setVisibile(true);
                 //long run action
                button1.setText("myText");
                 //long run action
                button1.setVisibile(true);
                //end of operations
            }
        )};
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the GUI freeze and all the elements are shown together at the end of the operations, I tried to see something about javafx thread management but I couldn't implement a satisfactory solution.. can someone help me?

Thank you all.

Comment: You are making the changes on the Application thread which pauses the app update(freeze's the app) while its running try wrapping your changes in `Platform.runLater(()-> ... )`

Comment: i tried this solution, unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Can you post a full runnable [mre] then but strip down the code so it doesn't have any extra code that we don't need to reporduce the issue

Comment: You can’t perform long-running actions in an event handler.  The UI cannot redraw itself (or respond to user input) until your handler returns.  That’s why it’s freezing.  You need to perform your long-running actions in a different thread and then use Platform.runLater like Matt suggested, or perform those actions in Task created by a [Service](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution leveraging the `java.util.concurrent` and `javafx.concurrent` APIs:

```
Executor exec = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

// ...

button.setOnAction(event -> {
    myPane.setVisible(true);
    Task<Void> task1 = createTask(this::doTask1, () -> label1.setVisible(true));
    Task<Void> task2 = createTask(this::doTask2, () -> label2.setVisible(true));
    Task<Void> task3 = createTask(this::doTask3, () -> button1.setText("myText"));
    Task<Void> task4 = createTask(this::doTask4, () -> button1.setVisible(true));
    List.of(task1, task2, task3, task4).forEach(exec::execute);
});

// ...

private Task<Void> createTask(Runnable longRunningProcess, Runnable onSucceeded) {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            longRunningProcess.run();
            return null ;
        }
    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(e -> onSucceeded.run());
    return task ;
}

private void doTask1() {
    // long running operation...
}
private void doTask2() {
    // long running operation...
}
private void doTask3() {
    // long running operation...
}
private void doTask4() {
    // long running operation...
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the tasks really need to run in succession?  Most programmers new to JavaFX seem to think about everything linearly - do this, then do that, wait for an answer, then do something else - which isn't usually the correct way to do it in a event driven environment.

Comment: @DaveB I wanted the answer to be consistent with the question, in which the four tasks were clearly executed in a linear fashion.  One advantage of this approach is that the change to running them in parallel is just a change to a single line of code (and could even be externalized using DI if required).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick runnable example in writing my comment I realized I glossed over the fact that it is not already on a different thread and was reminded when I read VGR's comment here is a runnable example I used just a `new Thread` for a simple demonstration but would recommend a `Task` or a `Service`. Note you can see that the Main Thread is not freezing by the fact that you can still click the `RadioButton`s

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Main APP"));

        Pane pane = new Pane(new Label("THIS IS INSIDE THE PANE"));
        vBox.getChildren().add(pane);

        Button button = new Button("Activate Pane Cloaking");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            new Thread(() -> {
                simulateCodeRunning();//5 sec
                Platform.runLater(() -> pane.setVisible(!pane.isVisible()));

                if (pane.isVisible())
                    Platform.runLater(() ->button.setText("Deactivate Cloaking"));
                else
                    Platform.runLater(() ->button.setText("Activate Pane Cloaking"));
            }).start();
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(button);

        ToggleGroup radioGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton radioButton1 = new RadioButton("Click Me");
        radioButton1.setToggleGroup(radioGroup);
        RadioButton radioButton2 = new RadioButton("Click Me");
        radioButton2.setToggleGroup(radioGroup);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(radioButton1, radioButton2);


        primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void simulateCodeRunning() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```